# Can I amplify a thermocouple Signal with the GS8332-SR OP-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, thermocouple, low-voltage

Theremocouples have a very small voltage of around 0.4mV/10C.
[K Type Thermocouple Voltage Table](https://www.thermocoupleinfo.com/type-k-thermocouple.htm)

I want to amplify that signal so I can read it with an ADC on my Arduino Microcontroller. The Voltage would be GND to +5V. Will the GS8332 IC do the job? 
[GS8332-SR Datasheet](http://file.elecfans.com/web1/M00/8A/32/pIYBAFyLivyAMIceAAStO11tF4s569.pdf?filename=1533885521534724518.pdf)

I am not sure because I don't see any CMVR data in there (first time reading OP-Amp Datasheets). The Offset Voltage is only 10uV so thats good. But could it be that there is more that I need to keep in mind?

Comment: Not sure about the op-amp, but be sure to understand "reference junction". https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/measuring-temp-using-thermocouples.html

Comment: @Mattman944 Don't worry, I will handle that seperately

Comment: What noise floor do you need? what bandwidth? if the opamp is an auto-zero or chopper, you'll have output spikes of 10 or 50 degree-C-error and need to filter out those spikes before ADC sampling.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf The signal will be DC only and won't change only very slowly. My maximum Noise Voltage would be to guarantee an accuracy of around +-5C; so around 200uV. I don't think the amplifier would create a noticable amount of noise as it was designed for low voltage applications.